# How can display variable only once?

Tags: php

i have a list of page order by id .Example:

```
example.com/a?id=4
example.com/a?id=3
example.com/a?id=2
```

In every page a have string {order_id} Now i want first time load page it replace {order_id} with the id in url , from the second time it replace with empty string

in my code , it only work when i refresh the page with the same url ( example.com/a?id=4 and reload it ) but go to ( example.com/a?id=3 then go back example.com/a?id=4 it's not work) . Here is my code :

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
if(isset($_SESSION['orderid']) && $_SESSION['orderid'] == $id){
        $this->mOutPut = str_replace('{order_id}',"", $this->mOutPut);
    }else{
        $this->mOutPut = str_replace('{order_id}',$id, $this->mOutPut);
    }
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['orderid'] = $id;
```

Comment: Are you missing the line $id=$_POST['id'];  ?

Comment: of course i have , just copy the error code part

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
session_start();
$id=$_POST['id'];
if(isset($_SESSION['orderid']) && $_SESSION['orderid'] == $id){
        $this->mOutPut = str_replace('{order_id}',"", $this->mOutPut);
    }else{
        $this->mOutPut = str_replace('{order_id}',$id, $this->mOutPut);
    }  
    $_SESSION['orderid'] = $id;
```

Comment: it still replace {order_id} = $id when go from a?id=4 -> a?id=3 -> a?id=4

Comment: it is because $_SESSION['orderid'] is just a variable holding your previous session id, not an array holding all your previous session ids

Comment: thanks for your advance .  i'll try change to store session in array